# pymongo insert error on mac sierra

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I recently installed mongodb using homebrew on mac sierra, and everything works fine; from import to connection. but when i tried to insert i got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 2467, in insert
    with self._socket_for_writes() as sock_info:
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 823, in _get_socket
    server = self._get_topology().select_server(selector)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 214, in select_server
    address))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 189, in select_servers
    self._error_message(selector))
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: timed out
```

I was using pymongo 3.4.3, then i downgraded to 2.8, then i go the following when connecting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 377, in __init__
    raise ConnectionFailure(str(e)) pymongo.errors.ConnectionFailure: timed out
```

Comment: Are you using ipv6 localhost connection?

Comment: No, I am using ipv4 localhost connection

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, i figured it out, I realized that my mongod was not actually started from the terminal.

All I had to do was start the mongod from terminal like so:

$ mongod